# Write new gem for using command line on terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

*Hi guys.*
I wanna learn how to write a new gem by myself (I'm newbie).
So I found some document to do it but it's quite hard for me.
I want to write a gem. So when I install it, I can use it on terminal, for example:

> $ search key_work

But all document just said that I have to use:

> $ irb -Ilib -rMygem

And then I can use it with `Mygem.search`.But it's not my purpose.
My question is "How I can write a code for key-word that can run on terminal?"
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: use bunder to generate a new gem structure, and also to conrtole your gem onload.... with for example `bundle exec ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not want to make a gem just yet. what you want - I think - is to make an executable. This does not require a full GEM.

I'll be making 2 assumptions here, you are on a UNIX system, and `~/bin` is in your PATH.

First make a file with the name of your program (for this example call proga) in your `~/bin` folder.

Start this file with (only first line matters)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# your code here
# p gets.strip
```

We just want to make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/proga`

If you really want to make a command line gem, you can find a good start here: http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/ and http://blog.excelwithcode.com/build-commandline-apps.html